# 20.04 crashes on suspend after upgrade from 18.04

Tags: 20.04, suspend, crash

After upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04, suspend crashes during the suspend request, or, crashes on resume. This is a desktop not a laptop.  It is the same bios and hardware as 18.04.

20.04 crashes several different ways.

- on suspend, usb turns off, fans and system LEDs stay on, screen goes blank, crash.
- on suspend, screen flashes random colors & characters, fans & usb stay on, crash.
- on resume, usb & fans turn on, after a few seconds usb turns off, black screen has grayed out login prompt, crash.

Suspending from the power icon or from the command line always crashes with fans running. Letting the machine suspend on timeout, always crashes on resume.
Obviously 20.04 does not work with this hardware but why did 18.04 handle it?

To get out of the corrupted state I hold the power button down for 10 seconds. The reset button sometimes works, sometimes won't. This is a very hard crash.

- Cpu: **Ryzen 3600**
- Mobo: **Gigabyte B450M-DS3H**
- Bios Version: **F50**

```
user@desk:~$ free -h 
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1.3Gi        13Gi       150Mi       1.3Gi        13Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi

user@desk:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60

user@desk:~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 user user 4096 May 23  2019 .
drwx------ 3 user user 4096 Aug 14 10:51 ..
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user 4096 May 23  2019 clock-override@gnomeshell.kryogenix.org

user@desk:~$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Aug 11 16:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Aug 11 16:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 11 16:36 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 11 16:38 openweather-extension@jenslody.de
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 11 16:31 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 11 16:32 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me your make/model # of your computer or motherboard, and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I added the requested info.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory`, and tell me what video card you have, and what driver version.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema The hardware successfully passed the google stressapptest.  I tried Kubuntu 20.04 but like Ubuntu 20.04 suspend failed.  I installed a mothballed HDD with Ubuntu 18.04 from May of 2019 and it successfully suspended (kernel 4.15.0-50).  Using the Software Updater I updated the HDD to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (kernel 4.15.0-112.113-generic 4.15.18).  18.04.5 successfully suspends.  Whatever failed in the 20.04 upgrade is resolved in 18.04.5.  I will abandon 20.04 and consider the problem fixed.

Comment: Had you done the BIOS update, and the swap mods? Is this CPU/RAM overclocked?

Comment: @heynnema I did not alter the BIOS in any way except for changing the boot drive from my SSD to my mothballed HDD.  The CPU & RAM are running at stock speeds.  I did not alter the swap file.

Comment: Remember that you came here for help. If you're not willing to try some/all of the suggested repairs, then you'll be stuck at 18.04.5 forever. Your choice, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed for the time being.  I appended `nomodeset` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`

Now the box successfully suspends and is noticeably faster too.  I made no hardware or bios changes.

`nomodeset` appears to have given 20.04's memory footprint the time it needs to become stable.

I will keep this box under observation in case other anomalies pop up.

Comment: For a system running Ubuntu 20.04 and a NVIDIA KM2100 inside `nomodeset` is freezing the boot process and also an external display is not used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

## overclocked

If your CPU or RAM are overclocked, please return them to default.

```
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user 4096 May 23  2019 clock-override@gnomeshell.kryogenix.org
```

## BIOS

Gigabyte B450M-DS3H

You have BIOS version F50.

There's a newer BIOS available, version F51, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450M-DS3H-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios)

[image]

**Note**: Make sure that I have the correct web page for your model #.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

## swap

Let's create a slightly larger /swapfile...

Confirm this line in /etc/fstab...

**Note**: Assure that there are no other lines containing "swap".

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

## memory

Ryzen processors are notorious for memory compatibility problems.

Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

CPU Support List: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450M-DS3H-rev-10/support#support-cpu

Memory Support List: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450M-DS3H-rev-10/support#support-doc

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried as miarbor suggested to add nomodeset to the grub, unfortunately with NVIDA graphic card, this screw-up the visualization of the whole system! I solved it rather by using the original NVIDA binary driver (proprietary, tested) not the open source X.OrgXserver recomended by Ubuntu developer! see picture[image: NVIDA graphic card]

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue on Ubuntu 20.04.
I checked the log File and found that there was some issue with ACPI.

I was able to resolve it by typing the following in Terminal:
`echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6F`

Found this answer here: http://jhshi.me/2015/11/14/acpi-error-method-parseexecution-failed-_gpe_l6f/index.html#.YHhsW4Mzbm4