# 20.04 freezes after waking up from suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend, amd-graphics

I think my problem is very similar to one already asked:

1. [20.04 crashes on suspend after upgrade from 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266986/20-04-crashes-on-suspend-after-upgrade-from-18-04)
2. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1882917 - I've also tired all the things this user has tried doing.
3. https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/1172 - something very similar happens on POP OS.

I think is something deeper and has to do with kernel. I am on AMD Ryzen 7 and this behaviour was reproduced on:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Ubuntu 21.04
- Pop OS 20.04
- Fedora 34

One distro that it worked without problems:

- Deepin 20

I had 3 sleepless days trying to setup my new machine, hopping from distro to distro and trying to find a solution to this.

Here are some useful command outputs:

```
$ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-memory                  
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 1
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 24GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: 4ATF1G64HZ-3G2E1
          vendor: Micron Technology
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: M471A2K43EB1-CWE
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 1
          serial: 419EE09E
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 3
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 4
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: e
       version: R1BET63W(1.32 )
       date: 04/12/2021
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux thinkpad 5.11.0-7614-generic #15~1622578982~20.04~383c0a9~dev-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 2 00:50:47 U x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.5 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.6 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.7 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5006
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.1 Serial controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816a (rev 0e)
02:00.2 Serial controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816b (rev 0e)
02:00.3 IPMI Interface: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816c (rev 0e)
02:00.4 USB controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 816d (rev 0e)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
05:00.0 Wireless controller [0d40]: Intel Corporation XMM7360 LTE Advanced Modem (rev 01)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
07:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02)
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev d1)
08:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
08:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
08:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
08:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
08:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
08:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

I also have full disk encryption turned on!

Let me know if there is any other information I can provide to help with this.

Comment: If anyone is looking/waiting for a solution, this is a better thread
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1230

Comment: Have just came across this issue while using Ubuntu 22.04 on Lenovo Ideapad 5 14 ARE 05, and it seems to present in the whole Lenovo Ideapad series using ryzen processors. This solution helped me out:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_IdeaPad_5_14are05#Enabling_S3_sleep

Answer (score 8):

## Fix

I had this issue* too, and if was fixed after I did the following:

### 1. Edit `/etc/default/grub`

1. Open with e.g. vim: `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`
2. Add `amd_iommu=off` to option of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. (For me it was `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to begin with, and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amd_iommu=off"` after editing.)

### 2. Update grub

Run `sudo update-grub`.

---

Found it in this guide: https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-ubuntu-18-04-crashes-freezes-after-sleep-suspend/

---

## *My issue

My exact issue as experienced before the fix (in case someone has a similar yet not identical problem).

##### Steps to reproduce

Same as asker, though you can also trigger it by simply making the screen go to sleep (standby) rather than suspending the computer.

1. Hit `ctrl+alt+L` to lock screen. Wait for screen to go black.
2. Hit any key to wake it back up.

##### Behavior

When screen woke up I could see the lock screen, but it was frozen; The caret in the password field was not blinking like it usually does, and input from mouse or keyboard did seem to do anything. The only exception was [REISUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Uses) (holding down `alt+SysRq` while typing `R`,`E`,`I`,`S`,`U`,`B`) which did reboot the machine.

Comment: I was searching for an answer for days!!! You saved me!

Comment: The guide link is dead. Do you happen to have an alternative one?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have another guide.

Comment: it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be suspend-related. Whenever the system was suspended it would freeze and not respond to anything but forced restart. So disabling the suspend feature for now has solved this problem.

- Disable all options to sleep:

  ```
  sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
  ```
- Stop system from sleeping on lid down:

  ```
  sudo vim /etc/systemd/logind.conf
  ```

  and add/update these 3 lines:

  ```
  [Login] 
  HandleLidSwitch=ignore 
  HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
  LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
  ```