# Microfreezes every 10 seconds Ubuntu 22.04.2 Wayland

Tags: 22.04, video, screen, amd-graphics, wayland

System:

```
Ubuntu 22.04.2
Kernel 5.19.0-32-generic
Session Wayland
```

Laptop:
[Lenovo ThinkPad T14s AMD Gen 1 (Laptop is certified with Ubuntu)](https://ubuntu.com/certified/202006-27978)

Uptime at moment when the problem found:

```
  16:47:28 up 2 days, 22:45,  1 user,  load average: 0.33, 1.52, 1.88
```

Common description:
After approx. 3 days of uptime (with sleep at night and on the way to work and back) there appears microfreezes every 10 (may vary, but during session the this same is constant) seconds.

[image: Here you can see FPS anomaly]

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.7 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Black SN750 / PC SN730 NVMe SSD
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.1 Serial controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111xP UART #1 (rev 0e)
02:00.2 Serial controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111xP UART #2 (rev 0e)
02:00.3 IPMI Interface: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111xP IPMI interface (rev 0e)
02:00.4 USB controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL811x EHCI host controller (rev 0e)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
05:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02)
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev d1)
06:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
06:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
06:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
06:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
06:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
06:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

`dmesg` after last sleep resume:

```
[142445.801629] docker0: port 1(vetha889e32) entered blocking state
[142445.801635] docker0: port 1(vetha889e32) entered disabled state
[142445.801794] device vetha889e32 entered promiscuous mode
[142446.048539] eth0: renamed from veth965ae15
[142446.100515] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vetha889e32: link becomes ready
[142446.100630] docker0: port 1(vetha889e32) entered blocking state
[142446.100635] docker0: port 1(vetha889e32) entered forwarding state
[142446.166093] docker0: port 2(vethd79f650) entered blocking state
[142446.166098] docker0: port 2(vethd79f650) entered disabled state
[142446.166247] device vethd79f650 entered promiscuous mode
[142446.166491] docker0: port 2(vethd79f650) entered blocking state
[142446.166496] docker0: port 2(vethd79f650) entered forwarding state
[142446.416929] eth0: renamed from veth767d05f
[142446.464516] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethd79f650: link becomes ready
[142446.521334] docker0: port 3(veth5f8c1b6) entered blocking state
[142446.521338] docker0: port 3(veth5f8c1b6) entered disabled state
[142446.521558] device veth5f8c1b6 entered promiscuous mode
[142446.521876] docker0: port 3(veth5f8c1b6) entered blocking state
[142446.521879] docker0: port 3(veth5f8c1b6) entered forwarding state
[142446.744540] eth0: renamed from vethab0b3fe
[142446.792805] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth5f8c1b6: link becomes ready
[142446.861870] docker0: port 4(veth29dcc56) entered blocking state
[142446.861876] docker0: port 4(veth29dcc56) entered disabled state
[142446.862044] device veth29dcc56 entered promiscuous mode
[142447.112393] eth0: renamed from vethd8b654b
[142447.136289] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth29dcc56: link becomes ready
[142447.136388] docker0: port 4(veth29dcc56) entered blocking state
[142447.136394] docker0: port 4(veth29dcc56) entered forwarding state
[144376.692212] pcieport 0000:00:08.1: PME: Spurious native interrupt!
[145511.903888] loop17: detected capacity change from 0 to 101624
[145512.613337] audit: type=1400 audit(1669730618.852:79): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/snapd/17883/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=426426 comm="apparmor_parser"
[145512.614170] audit: type=1400 audit(1669730618.852:80): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/snapd/17883/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=426426 comm="apparmor_parser"
[145512.701910] audit: type=1400 audit(1669730618.940:81): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.canonical-livepatch" pid=426430 comm="apparmor_parser"
[145513.577791] audit: type=1400 audit(1669730619.816:82): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.snapd-desktop-integration" pid=426431 comm="apparmor_parser"
[145513.590220] audit: type=1400 audit(1669730619.828:83): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.starship" pid=426446 comm="apparmor_parser"
[145513.590511] audit: type=1400 audit(1669730619.828:84): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.nativefier" pid=426440 comm="apparmor_parser"
[145513.590575] audit: type=1400 audit(1669730619.828:85): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.ncspot" pid=426442 comm="apparmor_parser"
[145513.594758] audit: type=1400 audit(1669730619.832:86): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.canonical-livepatch.hook.disconnect-plug-etc-update-motd-d" pid=426438 comm="apparmor_parser"
[145513.595714] audit: type=1400 audit(1669730619.832:87): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.canonical-livepatch.hook.connect-plug-etc-update-motd-d" pid=426437 comm="apparmor_parser"
[145513.597083] audit: type=1400 audit(1669730619.836:88): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.canonical-livepatch.hook.configure" pid=426436 comm="apparmor_parser"
[145514.842949] loop18: detected capacity change from 0 to 8

# Somewhere here I've run sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

[146666.783411] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[146666.783816] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[146666.783819] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[146666.783868] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 cc-a0-66.ucode
[146666.783874] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00002B7E | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[146666.783879] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00A022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[146666.783884] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[146666.783894] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x004FAA46 | branchlink2
[146666.783898] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x000018DC | interruptlink1
[146666.783902] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x000018DC | interruptlink2
[146666.783905] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0000FFA3 | data1
[146666.783908] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xFE8A8800 | data2
[146666.783912] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xFFEC5800 | data3
[146666.783915] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xFE4072B1 | beacon time
[146666.783920] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xD747A282 | tsf low
[146666.783924] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0000014C | tsf hi
[146666.783928] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[146666.783933] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x20322C47 | time gp2
[146666.783938] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[146666.783944] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000042 | uCode version major
[146666.783949] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xF1C864E0 | uCode version minor
[146666.783954] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version
[146666.783959] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00489000 | board version
[146666.783964] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x80FEFD25 | hcmd
[146666.783968] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00021000 | isr0
[146666.783972] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x004C0000 | isr1
[146666.783976] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x08F0000A | isr2
[146666.783979] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x04C3428D | isr3
[146666.783983] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[146666.783987] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x053E001C | last cmd Id
[146666.783990] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00014B16 | wait_event
[146666.783994] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x000000D4 | l2p_control
[146666.783998] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[146666.784002] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000007 | l2p_mhvalid
[146666.784005] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000081 | l2p_addr_match
[146666.784008] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[146666.784011] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[146666.784013] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0000A810 | flow_handler
[146666.784312] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[146666.784315] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
[146666.784317] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x20000070 | NMI_INTERRUPT_LMAC_FATAL
[146666.784319] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[146666.784320] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x80455A96 | umac branchlink2
[146666.784321] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x80473F9A | umac interruptlink1
[146666.784323] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x80473F9A | umac interruptlink2
[146666.784324] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000400 | umac data1
[146666.784326] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x80473F9A | umac data2
[146666.784327] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[146666.784329] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000042 | umac major
[146666.784330] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xF1C864E0 | umac minor
[146666.784331] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x20322D39 | frame pointer
[146666.784332] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xC0886260 | stack pointer
[146666.784334] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x002D010C | last host cmd
[146666.784335] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[146666.784608] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[146666.784610] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
[146666.784708] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x000066D2 | IML/ROM data1
[146666.784807] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[146666.784904] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[146666.784952] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x60000041 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[146666.784999] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[146666.785049] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[146666.785096] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[146666.785145] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[146666.785193] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[146666.785240] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[146666.785288] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[146666.785338] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[146666.785389] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[146666.785437] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[146666.785487] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[146666.785690] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
[146666.785697] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
[147386.770072] loop13: detected capacity change from 0 to 238984
[147387.423377] kauditd_printk_skb: 30 callbacks suppressed
[147387.423384] audit: type=1400 audit(1669732493.659:119): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/14399/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=437380 comm="apparmor_parser"
[147387.424237] audit: type=1400 audit(1669732493.663:120): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/14399/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=437380 comm="apparmor_parser"
[147387.579155] audit: type=1400 audit(1669732493.815:121): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.core.hook.configure" pid=437382 comm="apparmor_parser"
[147387.584009] audit: type=1400 audit(1669732493.823:122): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.core" pid=437439 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Here is recording of screen with phone in slow motion:

- https://youtu.be/0HJdLY2lMHc
- https://youtu.be/LU-w3-C-3TE

Tried solutions:

- [20.04 freezes after waking up from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347924/20-04-freezes-after-waking-up-from-suspend) - Not solved